# Change display format of DirectX "Object Table"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hlsl, directx-11

While debugging with VS 2012 Graphic's Debugger, I want to look at an index buffer, but the format that is showing it in is as float. This means the numbers are different than they would be with an int or short format.

Does somebody know how to change this?

Here is what the .txt file looks like.

```
The buffer format used is specified in the 'Graphics Object Table'.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Types:  bool, int, xint (an unsigned hex int), uint (unsigned int), int64, xint64, uint64, 
        byte, xbyte, ubyte, 2byte,  x2byte, u2byte, 4byte, x4byte, u4byte, 8byte, x8byte, u8byte,  
        half (a 16-bit float), half2, half3, half4, float, float2, float3, float4, double
Usage:  'float' or 'float3 xint half half xint'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Currently used format:  float
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

0   [0x00000000-0x00000003] |    +1.8367099e-040
1   [0x00000004-0x00000007] |    +9.1836897e-041
2   [0x00000008-0x0000000b] |    +4.2038954e-045
3   [0x0000000c-0x0000000f] |    +5.5101858e-040
4   [0x00000010-0x00000013] |    +3.6734899e-040
5   [0x00000014-0x00000017] |    +5.5102279e-040
6   [0x00000018-0x0000001b] |    +9.1836617e-040
7   [0x0000001c-0x0000001f] |    +8.2653208e-040
8   [0x00000020-0x00000023] |    +7.3469938e-040
9   [0x00000024-0x00000027] |    +1.2857138e-039
10  [0x00000028-0x0000002b] |    +1.1938797e-039
11  [0x0000002c-0x0000002f] |     +1.102047e-039
12  [0x00000030-0x00000033] |    +1.6530614e-039
13  [0x00000034-0x00000037] |    +1.6530628e-039
14  [0x00000038-0x0000003b] |    +1.5612301e-039
15  [0x0000003c-0x0000003f] |    +1.9285734e-039
16  [0x00000040-0x00000043] |    +5.5102138e-040
17  [0x00000044-0x00000047] |    +1.8367197e-039
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the format through the Graphics Object Table (menu Debug > Graphics > Object Table).

Select your index buffer in the table and then change its format using the Buffer Format combo box at the top of the Graphics Object Table.

Comment: I have visual studio 2012 and IT IS NOT letting me change the format. The only thing I can do from there is sort the different resources by format type. But no combo box that lets me change this. Are you 100% sure this works?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, I am also using VS 2012 and I was looking for the same thing yesterday. Take a look at the article here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873203.aspx). The combo box is just above the header row of the table in that picture.

Comment: You just took me to school brother man. I can't believe that was right there in front of me. Thanks again.